# Figuring out format of old video file

Tags: video, vlc

I have a home video that I must have ripped in the early 2000s. I'd like to view it, but it doesn't have an extension and shows up in the finder as a unix executable file. Opening with VLC gives me an error saying it doesn't know the codec. 
Any thoughts on how to get this open or viewable?

Comment: The file might be corrupt, but...did you try giving it a suffix ?. If you want them to be treated as HDV files, give them the suffix '.hdv' , as always be careful opening data files of unknown origin.

Comment: Do you remember what software and what platform you used to encode it with?  That will at least start the process of elimination.

Comment: You can try this program: [Is there a command analogous to afinfo for videos on a Mac OS X?](https://superuser.com/a/415099/130497)